# Calculus implicit differential

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

So i am here with my question , Question asks $(x-y)^2 = x + y - 1$.

$2 (x-y) (1- y') = 1 + y'$

I am a little confused when it comes to right here, can anyone clarify a little,

I know the step that should come next which is $2 (x-y) - 2 (x-y) y' = 1 + y'$
but how did they get $-2(x-y)y'$?

Comment: They are derivating both sides with respect to x, with the "implicit" assumption that $y\equiv y(x)$.

Comment: They multiply 2(x-y) by 1 and 2(x-y) by -y'

Comment: (OP changed the question after I answered)

Comment: ahm @kmitov can you put that as an answer so i can select it

Comment: At your request, I'll write up what you are looking for. Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field and so the distributive, associative and commutative properties hold among others. That is $a*(b+c) = a*b + a*c$, $(a+b)*c = a*c + b*c$, $-a = -1*a$, $a*b = b*a$ and $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c) = a*b*c$. So, $2*(x-y)*(1-y') = 2*[(x-y)*(1-y')] = 2*[(x-y)*1 + (x-y)*(-y')] = 2*(x-y) + 2*(x-y)*(-y') = 2*(x-y) - 2*(x-y)*y'.$

Comment: Very helpful comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the authors probably do is suppose that $y$ is a function of $x$. That way, you have that $$(x+y-1)' = (x)' + (y(x))' - (1)' = 1 + y' - 0$$
on the right side. The left side is best seen as a function of $x$ that maps $x$ to $(x-y(x))^2$. Differenting this gives $$2(x-y(x)) \cdot (x-y(x))'= 2(x-y(x))(1-y')$$